# Using localstorage inside Jquery done method

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage, web-storage

I want to set a localstorage inside .done method when user's answer is correct. Then i want to `get` that local storage object and use that outside of the `done` method. How is that possible? Below is what i am trying without success.

**data.color** is a string

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "validation.php",
    dataType: "json",
    data: $("input").serialize(),
}).done(function(data) {
 if (data.answer) { //if answer is correct
 localStorage.setItem("ColorStorage", data.color); //set a local storage with the variable data.color
    }
});

//outside of ajax
if (localStorage.getItem("ColorStorage") > 1)
    $("#result").append(localStorage.getItem("ColorStorage"));
```

Comment: Where are you having the trouble ? setting or getting ? To inspect it can you put `debugger;`s before your set and get and debug it ?

Comment: It's possible to get the value of locaStorage anywhere in the window because it's an object of window itself which keeps your data even after closing your browser.

Comment: Is data.color a number field

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: @janith1024 `data.color` is a string

Comment: @GragasIncoming See my answer below. To always be sure that the localStorage item is set. You need to do it inside the ajax callback function. If you don't you can never be sure that the ajax call has returned and triggered the callback function that sets your localStorage. Chaining `.done` functions can provide a solution in this case.

Comment: If data.color is string localStorage.getItem("ColorStorage") > 1 is not valid status. So remove >1 from the statement

Comment: so i should use `localStorage.getItem("ColorStorage").length > 1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The returned value from `localStorage.getItem("ColorStorage")` is a `String`, so compare it with e.g. a number like `> 1` won't work.

You can e.g. omit the `> 1` and it will return `true` if the item exist.

```
if (localStorage.getItem("ColorStorage"))  {

}
```

You can of course also check its `length`, though *after* you made sure it exists, or else you will get an error if it doesn't.

```
if (localStorage.getItem("ColorStorage") && localStorage.getItem("ColorStorage").length > 1)  {

}
```

---

Also do note, if you make that call before the AJAX call is `done`, the item won't exist, though with the above code sample it won't result in a runtime error.

Comment: yeah that was my issue. Now it works fine outside of Ajax. I can see that object from the browser application tab

Answer (score 0):

You can chain `.done` and wait until the item is set:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "validation.php",
    dataType: "json",
    data: $("input").serialize(),
}).done(function(data) {
 if (data.answer) { //if answer is correct
 localStorage.setItem("ColorStorage", data.color); //set a local storage with the variable data.color
    }
}).done(
if (localStorage.getItem("ColorStorage") > 1)
    $("#result").append(localStorage.getItem("ColorStorage"));
);
```

You need to chain `.done` functions to make sure that your item is set. If you leave it outside the `ajax` callback you are not sure if the `ajax` call has returned and successfully set your localStorage item. You will have to wait for it and then trigger your getItem function.

Comment: Did you miss _"...and use that outside of the `done` method"_

Comment: @LgSon No, but you can't be sure that when it reaches that line the localstorage item is set.

Comment: Exactly, hence your answer is completely wrong and should be focused on that issue instead...if that is the issue OP has, which we still don't know

Comment: Which for me makes the answer wrong (not technically though)